# Авторизация при внесении изменений в удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git, github, git-push

Я создал новый репозиторий на github. Далее, запустив git bush из корня целевой папки, я выполнил:

```
git init
git add . 
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Далее я добавил удаленный репозиторий:

```
git remote add origin <адрес>
```

Где адрес - это путь, скопированный с гитхаба для ssh?, начинающийся с "git@github.com:".

Создал ключ `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "..."`, запустил ssh-агент `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`, указал ему ключ `ssh-add "D:\newproject\_git_key"`. ввел пароль и сделал push.

В целом все удачно, но каждый раз, чтобы сделать push мне приходится после того, как я указываю ключ для ssh-агента, вводить свой пароль от гитхаба. Так и должно быть?

Comment: Вы не забыли добавить свой SSH-ключ в настройках аккаунта GitHub?

Comment: @andreymal, нет, не забыл. Скопировал содержимое файла .pub в новый ssh-ключ в настройках

Comment: @andreymal, я даже вижу в настройках, что он использовался уже

Comment: Пароль от гитхаба или пароль от ssh-ключа всё же?